# Consulta CEI (Cadastro Específico INSS) para retorno de dados

Tags: php

Estou tentando desenvolver uma classe de consulta que retornará os dados disponíveis pelo CEI (INSS).

Até o momento tenho os seguintes códigos:

```
/**
         * Retorna os parâmetros necessários para a consulta;
         * @throws Exception
*/
public static function getParams()
{
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $crawler = $client->get('http://www2.dataprev.gov.br/PortalSalInternet/faces/pages/calcContribuicoesEmpresasEOrgaosPublicos/inicio.xhtml');

    $body = $crawler->getBody();
    $headers = $crawler->getHeaders();
    $cookie = $headers['Set-Cookie'][1];

    if (!method_exists('phpQuery', 'newDocumentHTML'))
        require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'phpQuery-onefile.php';

    $doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($body, $charset = 'utf-8');
    $token = phpQuery::pq('form#formInicial input[name="DTPINFRA_TOKEN"]')->val();
    $viewstate = phpQuery::pq('form#formInicial input[name="javax.faces.ViewState"]')->val();
    $imgCaptcha = phpQuery::pq('form#formInicial img[name="formInicial:j_id41"]')->attr('src');

    $urlCaptcha = 'http://www2.dataprev.gov.br' . $imgCaptcha;
    $captchaBase64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($urlCaptcha));

    if ($viewstate == '')
        throw new Exception('Erro ao recuperar viewstate');

    return [
            'captcha' => $urlCaptcha,
            'captchaBase64' => $captchaBase64,
            'viewstate' => $viewstate,
            'cookie' => $cookie,
            'token' => $token,
            ];
}

/**
     * Metodo para realizar a consulta
     *
     * @param  string $cei CEI
     * @param  string $captcha Captcha
     * @param  string $viewstate ViewState
     * @param  string $token Token
     * @throws Exception
     * @return array  Dados da empresa
*/
public static function consulta($cei, $captcha, $viewstate, $token, $stringCookie)
{
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $arrayCookie = explode(';', $stringCookie);
    $urlCurl = 'http://www2.dataprev.gov.br/PortalSalInternet/faces/pages/calcContribuicoesEmpresasEOrgaosPublicos/inicio.xhtml';

     $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
     $param = [
               'body' => [
               'formInicial' => 'formInicial',
               'DTPINFRA_TOKEN' => $token,
               'formInicial:categoria' => 'EMPRESA',
               'formInicial:tipoDoDocumento' => 'CEI',
               'formInicial:cei' => $cei,
               'formInicial:captchaId' => $captcha,
               'formInicial:botaoPrincipalConfirmar' => 'Confirmar',
               'javax.faces.ViewState' => $viewstate
               ]
               ];
      $request = $client->createRequest('POST', $urlCurl, $param);
      $request->setHeader('Host', 'www2.dataprev.gov.br');
      $request->setHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0');
      $request->setHeader('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8');
      $request->setHeader('Accept-Language', 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4');
      $request->setHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate');
      $request->setHeader('Referer', 'http://www2.dataprev.gov.br/PortalSalInternet/faces/pages/calcContribuicoesEmpresasEOrgaosPublicos/inicio.xhtml');
      $request->setHeader('Cookie', $arrayCookie[0]);
      $request->setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
      $response = $client->send($request);
      echo $response;
}
```

Porém tenho o seguinte problema:

O site trabalha com sessão e envia a requisição do formulário para a mesma página validando essa sessão;

Ao enviar o método `consulta()`, normalmente acontece erros como sessão expirada ou ele somente carrega a tela inicial preenchendo os dados.

Alguém já fez algo parecido ou poderia me ajudar a solucionar essa situação?

Site para consulta:

> http://www2.dataprev.gov.br/PortalSalInternet/faces/pages/calcContribuicoesEmpresasEOrgaosPublicos/inicio.xhtml

Comment: Poderia colocar a sua solução como um comentário, para que outras pessoas possam usufruir dessa solução?

Comment: Seria melhor colocar como uma resposta.

Comment: Conforme solicitaram, a solução foi colocada a disposição dos usuários.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme solicitação, segue resolução do problema. Lembrando da utilização de classes externas:

- GuzzleHttp: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- PhpQuery: https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

  ```
  /**
   * Classe para consulta de dados utilizando CEI (Cadastro Específico do INSS)
   * @version 1.0
   * Class ConsultaCei
   */
  class ConsultaCei
  {

      /**
       * Retorna os parâmetros necessários para a consulta;
       * @return array
       * @throws \Exception
       */
      public static function getParams()
      {
          require 'vendor/autoload.php';
          $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
          $response = $client->get('http://www2.dataprev.gov.br/PortalSalInternet/faces/pages/calcContribuicoesEmpresasEOrgaosPublicos/inicio.xhtml');

          $body = $response->getBody();
          $headers = $response->getHeaders();
          $cookie = '';
          foreach ($headers['Set-Cookie'] as $cook) {
              $cookie .= trim($cook) . ';';
          }

          if (!method_exists('phpQuery', 'newDocumentHTML'))
              require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'phpQuery-onefile.php';

          $doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($body, $charset = 'utf-8');
          $token = phpQuery::pq('form#formInicial input[name="DTPINFRA_TOKEN"]')->val();
          $viewstate = phpQuery::pq('form#formInicial input[name="javax.faces.ViewState"]')->val();
          $imgCaptcha = phpQuery::pq('form#formInicial img[name="formInicial:j_id41"]')->attr('src');
          $urlCaptcha = 'http://www2.dataprev.gov.br' . $imgCaptcha;
          $captchaBase64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($urlCaptcha));

          if ($viewstate == '')
              throw new Exception('Erro ao recuperar viewstate');

          return [
              'captcha' => $urlCaptcha,
              'captchaBase64' => $captchaBase64,
              'viewstate' => $viewstate,
              'cookie' => $cookie,
              'token' => $token,
          ];
      }

      /**
       * Realizer a consulta
       * @param  string $cei CEI
       * @param  string $captcha Captcha
       * @param  string $token Token
       * @param  string $strCookie
       * @param  string $viewstate ViewState
       * @throws Exception
       * @return array
       */
      public static function consulta($cei, $captcha, $token, $strCookie, $viewstate)
      {
          require 'vendor/autoload.php';
          $arrayCookie = explode(';', $strCookie);
          $session = ';' . trim($arrayCookie[3]);
          $urlCurl = 'http://www2.dataprev.gov.br/PortalSalInternet/faces/pages/calcContribuicoesEmpresasEOrgaosPublicos/inicio.xhtml' . $session;
          $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

          $request = $client->createRequest('POST', $urlCurl, [
              'body' => [
                  'formInicial' => 'formInicial',
                  'DTPINFRA_TOKEN' => $token,
                  'formInicial:categoria' => 'EMPRESA',
                  'formInicial:tipoDoDocumento' => 'CEI',
                  'formInicial:cei' => $cei,
                  'formInicial:captchaId' => $captcha,
                  'formInicial:botaoPrincipalConfirmar' => 'Confirmar',
                  'javax.faces.ViewState' => $viewstate
              ],
              'headers' => [
                  'Host' => 'www2.dataprev.gov.br',
                  'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36',
                  'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                  'Accept-Language' => 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                  'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
                  'Referer' => 'http://www2.dataprev.gov.br/PortalSalInternet/faces/pages/calcContribuicoesEmpresasEOrgaosPublicos/inicio.xhtml',
                  'Cookie' => $strCookie,
                  'Connection' => 'keep-alive'
              ],
          ]);
          $client->send($request);

          $a = trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9\s]/', '', explode(':', $viewstate)[1]));
          $viewstate = str_replace($a, $a + 1, $viewstate);

          $request2 = $client->createRequest('POST', $urlCurl, [
              'body' => [
                  'formInicial' => 'formInicial',
                  'DTPINFRA_TOKEN' => $token,
                  'formInicial:categoria' => 'EMPRESA',
                  'formInicial:tipoDoDocumento' => 'CEI',
                  'formInicial:cei' => $cei,
                  'formInicial:captchaId' => $captcha,
                  'formInicial:botaoPrincipalConfirmar' => 'Confirmar',
                  'javax.faces.ViewState' => $viewstate
              ],
              'headers' => [
                  'Host' => 'www2.dataprev.gov.br',
                  'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36',
                  'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                  'Accept-Language' => 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                  'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
                  'Referer' => 'http://www2.dataprev.gov.br/PortalSalInternet/faces/pages/calcContribuicoesEmpresasEOrgaosPublicos/inicio.xhtml',
                  'Cookie' => $strCookie,
                  'Connection' => 'keep-alive'
              ],
          ]);
          $response2 = $client->send($request2);
          $body = $response2->getBody();

          if (!method_exists('phpQuery', 'newDocumentHTML'))
              require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'phpQuery-onefile.php';

          $doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($body, $charset = 'utf-8');
          $result = [];
          foreach (phpQuery::pq('div.linhaTipoB') as $dado) {
              $chave = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', phpQuery::pq($dado)->find('span:first')->html()));
              $chave = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ\s]/', '', $chave);
              switch ($chave) {
                  case 'CEI':
                      $chave = 'cei';
                      break;
                  case 'Razão Social':
                      $chave = 'razao_social';
                      break;
                  case 'Endereço':
                      $chave = 'endereco';
                      break;
                  case 'Bairro':
                      $chave = 'bairro';
                      break;
                  case 'Município':
                      $chave = 'municipio';
                      break;
                  case 'UF':
                      $chave = 'uf';
                      break;
                  case 'CEP':
                      $chave = 'cep';
                      break;
              }
              $valor = htmlspecialchars_decode(trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', phpQuery::pq($dado)->find('span.flutua')->html())));
              $result[$chave] = $valor;
          }
          return $result;
      }
  }
  ```

### Exemplo de uso:

```
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'ConsultaCei.php';
$cei = new ConsultaCei();
$params = [];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $resultado = $cei->consulta($_POST['cei'], $_POST['captcha'], $_POST['token'], $_POST['cookie'], $_POST['viewstate']);
    var_dump($resultado);
} else {
    $params = $cei->getParams();
    var_dump($params);
```

---

```
<form method="POST" name="formInicial" id="formInicial">
    <input type="hidden" name="viewstate" value="<?= $params['viewstate'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cookie" value="<?= $params['cookie'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?= $params['token'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cei" value="15.902.00984/03">
    <img src="<?= $params['captchaBase64'] ?>"><br>
    Digite o código da imagem: <input type="input" name="captcha" value=""><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```